# c# how to get input buffer property value as string

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo

I need to get the value of each property in an inputbuffer, I can get the name of the property but I can't get the value, I need to add the name and the value in a dictionary. This is my code:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> body = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo inputColumn in Row.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (!inputColumn.Name.EndsWith("IsNull"))
                body.Add(inputColumn.Name, Row.GetType().GetProperty(inputColumn.Name).GetValue(Row).ToString() );
    }
}
```

I got this exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: `inputColumn.GetValue(Row)`?

Comment: @DavidG in visual studio I get "argument 2: can't convert from object to string"

Comment: Sure, because `GetValue` returns `object`. If you know the type is actually a `string`, cast it.

Comment: Well `.ToString` will do the same thing (except it won't throw if it's not a string), it's not clear where you are getting that argument error from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call `GetValue` on the `inputColumn` object like this:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> body = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo inputColumn in Row.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (!inputColumn.Name.EndsWith("IsNull"))
        {
            body.Add(inputColumn.Name, 
               (string)inputColumn.GetValue(Row));
        }
    }
}
```

You can simplify the whole method with a bit of Linq, and also make it generic like this:

```
public void ProcessRow<T>(T item)
{
    var body = typeof(T) // Get the type
        .GetProperties() // Get all properties
        .Where(p => !p.Name.EndsWith("IsNull")) // Exclude properties ending with "IsNull"
        .ToDictionary( // Return a dictionary
            p => p.Name, 
            p => (string) p.GetValue(item));
}
```

You could also be even safer by making sure you only call properties that return string values with an additional `Where` clause:

```
.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
```

Or if you want to include other property types (e.g. `int`), then you will need to revert to using `ToString`:

```
p => p.GetValue(item).ToString()
```

That way you can reuse this method for other object types.

Comment: I get this error now : Can't convert System. Int32 to System.String

Comment: Because not all of your properties are strings. Either use the additional line I supplied at the end of my answer or revert to using `ToString` instead of casting.

Comment: Then you are not using my code, you need to show us your real code or there's nothing else I can do.

Comment: I've sort it, I had a null value in one of the property and it was raising the exception, it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should use variables for each method call, like `var rowType = Row.GetType();`.

`Row.GetType().GetProperty(inputColumn.Name)` can be replaced with `inputColumn` for example.

You can reuse variables in the same method and stack trace will show you the line where null reference is raised. Please check the stack trace, it will show you the method name that caused the error.

I suppose that `.GetValue(Row)` returns null.